# How to debug Magento 2.3 queue's consumers with Xdebug?

Tags: magento2.3, phpstorm, xdebug, queue, message-queue

I'm working with a Magento 2 queue at the moment. To debug Magento 2 console scripts I normally just hit 'listen to external connections' in PHPstorm and execute the CLI script (i'm using Valet+ with Xdebug on Mac).

With the new queue system of Magento 2.3 this, however, doesn't work. When I start my normal debugging workflow and I start queue processing with  `bin/magento queue:consumers:start someConsumer` and PHPstorm stops at the first line of `\Magento\MessageQueue\Console\StartConsumerCommand::execute`:

[image: Xdebug session with PHPstorm]

But it never reaches my actual consumer class. In my case this is `Vendor\Module\Model\Queue\Consumer::processMessage` (as specified in `queue_consumer.xml`). The `processMessage` function is executed, and the breakpoints aren't hit.

So, how do I setup Xdebug to debug queue consumers in Magento 2.3?

Answer (score 1):

First verify XDebug is enabled for CLI PHP:

```
php -i | grep xdebug
```

Set these environment variables in the (SSH) shell of the Magento instance, you may need to change the port and host:

```
export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=Local_Mac"
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_enable=1 remote_mode=req remote_port=9000 remote_host=127.0.0.1 remote_connect_back=0"
```

Now you can execute CLI commands which will use the above XDebug settings:

```
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start
```

Or you can start a specific consumer, for example `exportProcessor`:

```
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just extend the answer of **Jeroen Vermeulen - MageHost**

```
export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=Local_Mac"
```

Where 'Local_Mac' is name of settings in phpstorm **PHP/Servers/Name** (isn't a virtualhost or etc.)

```
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_enable=1 remote_mode=req remote_port=9003 remote_host=127.0.0.1 remote_connect_back=0"
```

**remote_port=9003** for xDebug 3.x